# Azure free account - does it cover SQL Managed Instance?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance

I have started using my free Azure account and I found out that I cannot create SQL Managed Instance. I get a cryptic error message telling me to change subscription or region, no clear information. The list of free services does not include SQL MI but it does not mean much. SQL Dedicated Pool or Synapse are also not listed but I tried to create them and the Portal does not complain yet even though I did not click the final Create button yet.

Comment: Btw it will help if you provide a screenshot of the error, or just quote the exact error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So SQL Managed Instances are only [available on certain subscription types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/resource-limits#supported-regions). See:

[image: Supported subscription types]

You probably have an Azure Trial subscription. If not, you might also want to check your region as there are region limitations as mentioned in the article above.

Comment: Yes, this is Trial account/subscription. I did not realize that it can be mixed with Pay-as-you-go and still be free. I have to read about this more

Comment: Yes generally anything you subscribe that's out of scope for credits, you'll just be charged for them! Btw if you think my reply answered your question, please mark it accordingly, else if it's only helpful but did not answer, you can upvote it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is now a new free SQL MI offering - free to try azure AQL Managed Instance for up to 12 months https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/free-sql-managed-instance/ba-p/3944706